# How to use Gitlab CI generated artifact in an API call?

Tags: json, go, gitlab

I am using a Go microservice where I need to parse a Newman report. Currently, I am taking the Newman report from the local directory as follows:

```golang
jsonFile, err := os.Open("outputfile.json")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

But I need to generate the report in Gitlab CI as follows:

```yaml
  image:
    name: postman/newman
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo "Generating newman report"
    - pwd
    - newman --version
    - newman run collection.json --reporters cli,json --reporter-json-export outputfile.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - outputfile.json
```

Is there any way I can use this report from GitLab CI (maybe using CURL) and take the report as an API-driven input, rather than taking it from the local directory?

Comment: You can use the Artifacts API https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `cURL` without any problem.

Let's suppose you are in the organization `ORG` within the project `PROJECT` in the `master` branch and that your aforementioned defined job is called `generate_newman`.

You could download the last generated artifact as follows:

```
curl -L https://gitlab.com/ORG/PROJECT/-/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=generate_newman
```